# React require Hard refresh to show last changes

Tags: reactjs, caching, build

Every time I update my website, the users need to do a Hard refresh to see the last changes

I search this issue but no result, tried added Tags in my Html file to avoid save cache in my app, the unregister function from the serviceWoker and the library of react-clean-cache but none seem to work

Is there a way to force Browser load my page from scratch ?

React v16.13.1
Node v13.13.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use useHistory from react-router-dom. And then history.go(0) to force the refresh  actual page.

Comment: It doesn't clear the cache just redirect to the first page